# Script hashes the files name and not the lines one by one

Tags: python, hash, hashlib

I recently wrote a script so that Python will open, read the file, hash the passwords in the file one by one and then save it to a separate file. But when I run the script, the hashlib module does not has the passwords one by one, but instead hashes the password name. Here is the script:

```
import hashlib

word_list = input("Input file name to pull words from: ")
hash_list = input("Input list to hash to: ")
h = hashlib.sha512()

f = open(word_list, 'r')
f.readline()
g = open(hash_list, 'w')

for word in word_list:
    word = word.strip('\r\n')

    h.update(word.encode())
    hashed_word = h.hexdigest()
    g.write(hashed_word)
```

I have tried different files with the same passwords in it, I have tried different named files with the same single password. When I run it with a different named file but the same password, it gives me a different hash. (Which I assume is the hash for the name of the file, because the hash is the same except for the end of it. Example filenames hash1 and hash2 have the same characters in the hash, but near the end they are different.

Comment: `word_list` is the filename of the password file.  It is not the file contents.

Comment: Yes, word_list is the variable that represents the file. As I run the for loop, it is saying, "read word from filename variable word_list.

Comment: `for word in word_list:` This loop makes no sense, because word_list is the NAME of the file, not its CONTENTS.  You are looping over the individual letters in the NAME of the file.

Comment: @John Gordon is 100% right. You need to open that file and read the individual lines.

Comment: How would I structure the loop so it will read the individual lines instead of the file?